# php import containing multiple functions calling each others

Tags: php

So I have two files:

test.php

```
<?php
require 'tools/tools.php';
check();
```

tools.php

```
<?php
function initDB(): PDO{
    require 'db-config.php'; //contains just the $DB_ vars definition
    echo ('db connection start...');
    return new PDO($DB_DSN, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $BD_OPTIONS);
}

function check(){
    echo ('check start...');
    $PDO = initDB();
    ... // Do other stuff
}
```

I'm new to php but this is very strange to me, if add a call to check() in tools.php, everything works fine, check() call initDB() and carry on with his job.

But if I execute it test.php only the check() function seems to be called and it seems to crash on initDB() call.

I tried to inspect it with echoes to see where it stops and with check.php I never see the 'db connection start...' printed, only the 'check start...' and nothing.

Is there something I don't get with import/require? I assumed that i would load the entire content of the required file and that it would be usable in the file that imported it (the require 'db-config.php' works fine) and since the initDB() is already in the same file as the check() i can't see why it wouldn't be able to access it.

Comment: Where is `db-config.php` located?  Maybe you need to change it to the full path to the file?

Comment: Add this to the top of the script. It should show more errors. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @JasonK Thanks you! Thanks to this error display I noticed that the error is indeed related to the db-config.php require. What I didn't think of was that after importing the content of the file, the path to db-config.php would now be relative to the file who imported tools.php and not tools.php anymore... It seems so obvious now ^^
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved thanks to @JasonK you showd me how to display errors.

As @Rocket Hazmat said the error is indeed related to require db-config.php;

Since include/require import only the content of the file and not simply link to it, any relative path on the included file is now relative to the file who did the inlcude/require.